# Should I use 2-way aggregation or are there better solutions?

Tags: java, arraylist, aggregation

I am working on a simple search engine and right now I have a class `Directory` which contains an `ArrayList<Person>` that contains objects from the `Person` class. The `Person` class has a name, surname and email. The `Directory` class has a `searchPerson(String searchTerm)` method, that goes through the ArrayList of the `directory` class and returns the Persons that have either a name, surname or email that equals the searchTerm. Not too difficult.

```
public class Directory {
    private List<Person> directory;

    // constructors, getters and setters

    public List<Person> searchPerson(String searchTerm) {
        List<Person> found = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person person: this.directory) {
            if (person.toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm)) {
                found.add(person);
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surName;
    private String email; 

    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

However, in the next section of the project (I am doing a project on JetBrains), the list must be searched according to 3 different search strategies: (There may be multiple searchTerms at once)

- ALL: Only return the Persons that equal all of the searchTerms.
- ANY: Return all Persons that equal at least one of the searchTerms
- NONE: Only return the Persons that equal none of the searchTerms.

They advise me to use the strategy design pattern. As such, I created an abstract class `searchStrategy` and gave the `Directory` an instance variable of the type `SearchStrategy`. Next, I created three concrete classes, all of which extending `SearchStrategy`, called: `SearchALL`, `SearchANY` and `SearchNONE`. Now, different searchStrategies could be implemented (haven't done so yet).

```
public class Directory {
    private List<Person> directory;
    private SearchStrategy strategy; // reference to the strategy

    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

However, now comes the question: the three `Search###` classes mentioned in the former paragraph do not have access to the ArrayList of persons of the `Directory` class (which, ofcourse, is the list they must search through).

Should I now as a solution give the `SearchStrategy` class an instance variable which refers to the same `ArrayList<Person>` in the `Directory` so that the Search Strategies can access it? This would result in (a sort of) 2-way aggregation (`Directory` has a `SearchStrategy` and an `ArrayList<Person>` and  `SearchStrategy` has the same `ArrayList<Person>`) and really feels weird.

```
// let's say I'd give this class a reference to the ArrayList
public class SearchALL extends SearchStrategy {
    private ArrayList<Person> directory // now they (kinda) point to each other
}
```

Or should I simply move the `ArrayList<Person>` from the `Directory` to the `SearchStrategy`?

Thus, I was wondering, is this bad practice and should I avoid it? And how should I implement my Search Engine programme?

Edit: Added some code. Removed the last section (Was only confusing)
Edit2: Even though (I think) this scenario may quite easily solvable (because all that is different among the search strategies are the conditions), I was wondering what one should do in general.

Comment: Please, less wall of text and more code. Stack Overflow is about code not linguistics.

Comment: What ••is•• the “Strategy”?  Is it any more than deciding whether a given Person satisfies a given Criteria - whether all, sone or none of conditions in that criteria.  As such, as per https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern , is the Strategy aware of the Context (ie does the strategy need access to the whole ArrayList) ?

Comment: My bad, will see if I can add more code.

Comment: @racraman uhm, yes I think it needs access to the ArrayList right? Or do you suggest the looping through the List etc. is done in the `Directory` class and only the criteria change per strategy (because I think only the criteria changes per strategy and nothing more)? How would I implement it then? Will think this through later, am now in a hurry

Comment: @racraman even though in this case the search strategies may not need to be aware of the ArrayList, how should I implement it if it DID have to be aware of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is to have the strategy implementation having a method for searching with the key words and the list as parameters.

First, you need the reference to a strategy and the setter for it. Second, your searching method just passes the arguments to the strategy implementation.

```java
class Directory {
    private List<Person> entries;
    private SearchStrategy strategy;

    List<Person> search(String a, String, b, String c) {
        return strategy.search(entries, a, b, c);
    }

    // setter for strategy
}
```

```java
interface SearchStrategy {
    List<Person> search(List<Person> list, String a, String b, String c);
}
```

```java
class SearchAll implements SearchStrategy {
    @Override
    List<Person> search(List<Person> list, String a, String b, String c) {
        // do your thing and return the result
    }
}
```

The point of the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is to seperate an algorithm from a class so the algorithm can be changed dynamically. To move the list into the algorithm implementing class is not a good idea as it will mix up the *algorithm* with the *data* it is working on. To have a reference in the algorithm implementing class is also bad for the same reason. The `Directory` class is the correct place.

Comment: OK, thanks! This really clears things up. Passing the list and search terms as parameters makes sense I guess, but I do have one question about it: in the scenario that the algorithm has been cut into many smaller methods (in the same class), a lot of these methods would also now have to take the List<Person> and search term as parameters to be able to do something with the data(right?), but then you'd get a whole bunch of methods all with the same parameters. Is that considered bad practice or does this not matter?

Comment: @ReefG Yes, right. It's not bad practice. It's a very straightforward and easy-to-understand approach to the problem, which is always a good thing. Of course, there can be better alternatives but you need to decide that for the specific case. What matters most is that the code is easy to change, use and understand. Some additional parameters won't affect those things negatively.